# How do I change the default locale in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, server, locale

I have a remote server which I installed and have been trying to unsuccessfully change the locale to french for a few hours. Below are the contents of my locale files:

`/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8
```

`/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`:

```
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB ISO-8859-1
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
fr_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_CH.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_LU.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_FR ISO-8859-1
```

Everything is still defaulting to english dates and the $ currency in my web app.
Is there something else I'm overlooking?
I should also mention that I have dpkg re-configured and restarted the server after changes were made.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Run the command `locale` - it should show your current locale.

Generate the locales for french:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Also, try regenerating the supported locale list by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

And update/change the current default locale:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

#### Update

Extra steps to try:

1. Try:

   ```
   sudo update-locale LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="fr_FR"
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```
2. Perhaps adding LANG and LANGUAGE in `/etc/environment` could force a change. Try logout/login or rebooting.
3. `locale` will show your current locale for the current user. Perhaps it's worth checking out these files just to be sure no local language variables are set: `~/.profile` `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile`

More info:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale
- https://serverfault.com/questions/228474/correctly-changing-default-locale-in-ubuntu-server-10-04-lts

Comment: Jus a quick question. Does the system need to be restarted for changes to take effect?

Comment: I think a logout/login should do it

Comment: wish it did. I ended up having to hardcode the values into the app and updating

Comment: try `sudo update-locale LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="fr_FR"` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Finally, perhaps adding LANG and LANGUAGE in `/etc/environment` could force a change. Try rebooting, maybe it's required for server services. :)

Comment: Also found this question and website that could prove useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/228474/correctly-changing-default-locale-in-ubuntu-server-10-04-lts - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: `sudo update-locale var=locale` and restart worked for me in ubuntu server 16.04.

Comment: @DarkStar1 About restarting the system, I had to restart.

Comment: languages in .bashrc was the problem. This was a tricky one to find. Changing the language, then just close and restart the terminal emulator, it works.

Comment: worked well! Thank you :)

Answer (score 12):

You also have to edit `/etc/profile`:

```
export LANG="en_US.utf8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.utf8"
```

Comment: Weird how few people mention this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I tried everything from `sudo locale-gen` and `sudo update-locale` to `sudo update-locale`, and manually making entries in `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/environment` with and without restarting.

Nothing seemed to work and my Python code was still throwing a Unicode error on Ubuntu 18.04l. Finally modifying the environment variable in `~/.bashrc` worked.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Of course don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc`

I know it's not the recommended way, but nothing else worked for me.

Comment: Of course this then has to be done to *every* user's .bashrc and also be added to the skelton for new users.....

Comment: All the above solutions didn't work only this one worked for my Elixir setup on Ubuntu 18 docker container. Thanks