# Weird issue with bootstrap icons on html pages

Tags: firefox, icons, google-chrome

I'm on top of Ubuntu 13.04, and when Firefox (and/or Chrome) renders a bootstrap icon, the result is the one I show on the screenshot.

[image]

<sub>Click to open a full-resolution image.</sub>

I don't find any info about this issue, anyone has a clue about what's happening?

Comment: What locale are you using?

Comment: es_ES. I've followed this steps http://askubuntu.com/a/89983/135846 to reset it (it was perfectly set before, but anyway...). No luck.

Comment: Usually I would think this is a locale issue, but I'm not sure - can you see the icons on http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons ?

Answer (score 1):

As i have this issue for a long time .. :)

The issue that in my Firefox settings (Content-> Advanced) .. 
I didn't check this option (Allow pages to use their own fonts,instead of my selection above) ..

So when rendering with my font .. I lost the icons ..

I hope that your issue is the same as mine .. to be solved with this solution .. :)