# How to use use period (.) as decimal separator in Qalculate / qalc?

Tags: configuration, locale

I use [Qalculate!](https://qalculate.github.io/) as my calculator tool. It comes with a command-line companion tool "qalc". I discovered that it uses comma "`,`" as decimal separator in numbers. Because the comma is already taken for that role, it expects semicolon "`;`" instead of comma "`,`" in function calls:

> Functions is normally entered in an expression by writing the name followed by arguments, **separated by** commas (or **semicolons in languages with comma as decimal point**), in parenthesis, thus following the syntax name(arg1, arg2, ...). ([source](https://qalculate.github.io/manual/qalculate-functions.html))

That's a mess. As a programmer, I will never remember to use semicolon to separate function arguments, and will always get errors like this at first:

> ```
> $ qalc "binomial(5, 3)"
> error: You need at least 2 argument(s) (Exponent; Index) in function binomial().
> ```

So how can I configure `qalc` to use period "`.`" as decimal separator and consequently comma "`,`" as parameter separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Set `decimal_comma=0` in the following two configuration files:

- `~/.config/qalculate/qalc.cfg` for the command-line calculator tool
- `~/.config/qalculate/qalculate-gtk.cfg` for the GUI calculator tool

### Alternative Solutions

- **A command line option.** As a non-permanent way to provide the same configuration as above, you can call `qalc` like this:

  ```
  qalc -set "decimal comma off" "binomial(5, 3)"
  ```
- **A command in interactive mode.** When you start the command-line tool as just `qalc` you are in interactive mode. There, you can apply the same configuration as above by entering this command and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>:

  ```
  set decimal comma off
  ```
- **Changing the locale.** Qalculate! evaluates `LC_NUMERIC` from your system's locale settings to determine what character to use as decimal separator ([source](https://github.com/Qalculate/libqalculate/issues/73#issuecomment-376444378)). The remaining character of period and comma then becomes the parameter separator. So execute `echo $LC_NUMERIC` to see if it's right. If not, you might want to [change or fix your locale settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/89976).
- **"Ignore locale" option.** [Starting with version 3.0](https://qalculate.github.io/news.html), there is an option to ignore the system locale and instead use English. Usage: `qalc -set "ignore locale" "binomial(5, 3)"`. Or in the `qalc` interactive mode, use `set ignore locale`. ([source](https://github.com/Qalculate/qalculate-gtk/issues/78#issuecomment-479357528))