# Fillable PDF Arabic Problems

Tags: pdf

i use many PDF viewer to filling PDF in Arabic but all are not OK , for example in document viewer text in Arabic didn't appear. i looked for solution but i didn't find, pleas help

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Arabic and https://askubuntu.com/questions/89976/how-do-i-change-the-default-locale-in-ubuntu-server

Comment: Late welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you edit the question and list some tools you have tried and a screenshot if possible.