# combine single text with multiple lines of file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying to combine work **tvg-name** with multiple lines of a file

```
tr '\n' '~' < file1.txt | sed s/~/tvg-name/g
```

results in  only first single-line print

```
tvg-namegama1
```

my file1.txt has more than 50 lines e.g.

```
gama1
beta2
tera3
```

and so on more than 50 lines

required output

```
tvg-name="gama1"
tvg-name="beta2"
```

and so on till the file ends.

Comment: question edited as requested. please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sed` alone, like so:

```bash
sed 's/.*/tvg-name="&"/' file1.txt
```

That will prepend `tvg-name="` and append `"` to each line in your file.

That can also be done with `awk`, like so:

```bash
awk '{printf "tvg-name=\"%s\"\n", $0}' file1.txt
```

Or with pure `bash`, like so:

```bash
while IFS= read -r l; do printf 'tvg-name="%s"\n' "$l"; done < file1.txt
```

Comment: this result in "tvg-name="gama1 , require result tvg-name="gama1"

Comment: @Rizwan.A Check your current `locale` https://askubuntu.com/q/89976 … You might need to change it to some standard English .,. The effect you describe can be as a result of e.g. right to left locale … The above `sed` command can’t do that … You can pipe the output to a file and check.

Comment: @Raffa it's more likely that the input file has CRLF line endings I think

Comment: @Rizwan.A If you have edited your file on Windows at some point, then your file could have Windows style carriage return line endings instead of the Unix/Linux newline and that could also result in mangling the output ... Check your file withe the `file` command like so `file file1.txt` and see if it prints `CRLF line endings` ... If so then you need to sanitize your file first https://askubuntu.com/q/803162 ... Thanks @steeldriver